# How to define shared variables in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, tokens

I am going to define shared variables in a multisite setup, say, to keep the value of 'manager_email'. I know that it can be done using an included php file like [this](http://drupal.org/node/70472). But for the sake of simplicity of maintenance and better integration, I am looking for a GUI solution to do so. I appreciate your hints.